# MySql WHERE syntax error

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm facing a unhandled exception said
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
    near ''table' WHERE column='value'' at line 1
when execute `MySqlDataReader.ExecuteReader()`.
This is example of the query

```
   SELECT column1,column2,column3,column3 " +
    "FROM 'table' " +
    "WHERE column='" + value + "'";
```

which value is string(utf8).
I tried to search WHERE syntax error but can't figure out where is an error in query.

Comment: That's not even close to valid SQL. It looks like was incorrectly ripped from a large context (and a good context in questions *means a lot*). In any case, use *parameter queries* with Command Parameters.

Comment: @user2864740 what that in this query which makes it `not even close to valid SQL`? Apart from single quotes around table name theres nothing wrong with that query

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky The fact that it is ripped from a C# expression of string literal concatenations.. again, context.

Comment: @user2864740 I typed this query myself, but The others part of query in my code is totally valid because I copied it, So it my fault that I'm not paying attention to query and end up that waste my time for a hour :(.

Comment: @user3578245 Using [@"verbatim strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx) can make copy'paste work *much* better. The addition of using [command parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) makes the query itself a tidy bundle without any `+`'s required - not only does this prevent SQL Injection but it results in a query that is much easier to also copy'paste out, such as to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table names for MySQL should never be inside quotation marks

```
'table'
```

You can use backticks ( ` ) if need be, but not single or double quotes. For example

```
SELECT column1,column2,column3,column3 FROM `table`
```

And your `WHERE` clause is fine

Comment: Does this rule only apply to MySQL? btw, Why I used single quotes with table even above of my code didn't use it XD. thanks.

Comment: Cant list all the databases to which this is the case but for MySQL it surely is

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
`
```

in mysql rather than `'`